# Why is the dividing set nonempty when a convex surface has Legendrian boundary?

Tags: geometric-topology, symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

I am an undergrad and curious about the following question. Let (Y,ξ) be a contact manifold, and L⊂(Y,ξ) be a Legendrian knot which is the boundary of a convex surface Σ embedded properly in Y.

Why is the dividing set on Σ nonempty?
I know you can use Stokes' theorem to prove the statement for the closed case, but I don't see how it helps for the Legendrian boundary case.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The same argument works in the relative case. Consider the integral of $d\alpha$ over the convex surface. Since the boundary is Legendrian, $\alpha$ vanishes identically on it. Thus $d\alpha$ has to change sign.